# VBA Search Single Column

Tags: vba

New to asking questions on this site, and to VBA so please bear with me... I'm compiling this database that is linking drawing numbers that show the same items but each drawing shows a different aspect of that particular 'area' shown in the drawing (I Hope that makes sense). The function that i would like to have is to be able to search just the A column for a value, and return the all of the unique times that the value shows up in the A column and the corresponding B column value. I thought that even with my paltry VBA skills i could manage this but I dont have much so far. This is what i have:

```
Dim ISO As String
Dim Rng As Range
ISO = InputBox("ISO Number: ", "Enter ISO Number")
If Trim(ISO) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=ISO)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox ("Nothing Found")
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use Autofilter ?

Comment: Just to check - you want to do two things 1) count the occurrences and 2) get the values in column B on the matching rows? Where do you want to put the column B matches?

Comment: @Absinthe, Yes, I tried my best to describe the requirements im glad you understand. I was thinking a msgbox that listed the column b matches would work best. So i know i need to store the b column variables somehow and thats where im getting hung up

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Im going to be passing this spreadsheet back off to other guys who dont quite understand all of the excel tools. For them to effectively use the sheet I think a command button would work best.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a for loop to iterate over the cells.

```
Sub FindMatches()

Dim ISO As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim foundCount As Long
Dim endString As String

ISO = InputBox("ISO Number: ", "Enter ISO Number")

If Trim(ISO) <> "" Then
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' always best to use a variable for an object if possible
    lastRow = ws.Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' work out how many rows to loop through
    For x = 1 To lastRow ' use a for loop to iterate over each row
        If ws.Cells(x, 1) = ISO Then
            foundCount = foundCount + 1
            endString = endString & ws.Cells(x, 2) & vbNewLine ' add column B to the string
        End If
    Next x
End If

MsgBox "Found " & foundCount & " matches: " & vbNewLine & endString

End Sub
```

For faster processing you could use an array rather than read from the cells one at at time:

```
Sub FindMatchesArray()

Dim ISO As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim foundCount As Long
Dim endString As String
Dim arr() As Variant

ISO = InputBox("ISO Number: ", "Enter ISO Number")

If Trim(ISO) <> "" Then
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' always best to use a variable for an object if possible
    lastRow = ws.Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' work out how many rows to loop through
    arr = ws.Range("A1:B" & lastRow).Value
    For x = 1 To lastRow ' use a for loop to iterate over each row
        If arr(x, 1) = ISO Then
            foundCount = foundCount + 1
            endString = endString & arr(x, 2) & vbNewLine ' add column B to the string
        End If
    Next x
End If

MsgBox "Found " & foundCount & " matches: " & vbNewLine & endString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Find` and `FindNext`.
The first `Test` will return the values in a message box, the second will place the returned values in cell `A1` on `Sheet2`.
I could've sworn this should work as a Worksheetfunction, but no luck (`.FindNext` won't work in a UDF).

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyMessage As String
    MyMessage = ReturnCountAndValue("5", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1))
    MsgBox MyMessage, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub

Sub Test2()

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = ReturnCountAndValue(.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K2"), _
                                                                .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F9"))
    End With

End Sub

Public Function ReturnCountAndValue(SearchValue As String, _
                                    SearchColumn As Range) As String

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim sTempReturn As String
    Dim lCounter As Long

    With SearchColumn
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=SearchValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            Do
                lCounter = lCounter + 1
                sTempReturn = sTempReturn & rFound.Offset(, 1).Value & vbCr
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)

            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress

            sTempReturn = lCounter & " items found. " & vbCr & _
                          sTempReturn

        Else

            sTempReturn = SearchValue & " not found in range " & SearchColumn.Address

        End If
    End With

    ReturnCountAndValue = sTempReturn

End Function
```